# Trying to solve randomly generated non-linear simultaneous equations using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sympy
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
a = "$y - $x - $"
b = "$x**2 + $y**2 + $x"
for n in range (0,len(a)):
    if a[n] == '$':
        a = a[:n] + str(randint(1,4)) + a[n+1:]
for n in range (0,len(b)):
    if b[n] == '$':
        b = b[:n] + str(randint(1,20)) + b[n+1:]
print(a,b)
answer = [solve([a,b],x,y)]
question = "2) Solve the simultaneous equations" + '\n' + a + '\n' + b + '\n'    
print(answer)
```

I am trying to make a program that randomly generates non-linear simultaneous equations and solves them but I don't know how to solve them. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd go the other way around. Begin with the solutions : `x = -2`, `x = 3` or `y = 2*x`, write the corresponding equation `(x+2)*(x-3)*(y-2*x) = 0`, expand it (e.g. `sympy.expand((x+2)*(x-3)*(y-2*x))`), move some terms to the right side. You're sure that the equations admits a solution and you don't need to solve the equation.